# How to find motherboard model from offline HDD

Tags: windows-8, laptop, motherboard, hp-elitebook

My HP 8540w laptop had a water spill accident and motherboard is damaged.
I don't remember exact specs about which CPU is there and other model details.
Is there any way to get this info on HDD when connected externally?
I'd like to order it and replace myself but I don't want to open the laptop until I am sure I can obtain that board myself.
Its a Win 8 system.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're one of those people who threw out all documentation that came with it? Usually you get an invoice, manual, etc from which you can get the exact specifications, albeit by googling some of the information found in those documents... serial numbers, part numbers etc printed on the computer will all help.

From the HDD, you can probably detect from the drivers that you installed which components you have, but it's MUCH easier and faster to open the plastic covers from your laptop and google some of the serial numbers found on the components. You don't need to take everything apart bit by bit.

Comment: I don't throw out the documentation and it's not in the invoice. All docs only mention 8540w in general. I will check the box to be sure. Serial also did not help on HP sites with products search.

Comment: Then check some serial numbers from the components on your mobo. Check the link below on the disassembly video.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looking at [HP 8540w](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02030608-4%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) would help. If you need to replace the motherboard, you need to get the exact model for this, as others may look similar but not fit the casing openings for connectors, etc.

I would recommend buying a new one and selling all good parts as spares, you might be surprised you can get good money out of them.

Comment: Unless you have the option to get the computer repaired via extended warranty I wouldn't recommend replacing the mobo on a laptop.  Its a pain in the butt and they can be REALLY expensive since the GPU is typically built into it.

Comment: Selling it for parts isn't really for me. This is high-end laptop and very few people have it as a personal laptop, at least in my country and I'm not willing to disassemble and ship it around the world as parts.

Comment: You can sell the **complete laptop** as **not working, for parts** on ebay as well. You don't have to disassemble it completely and sell part by part. There are plenty people out there who refurbish equipment and then resell. There could be more damage than just the mobo and repair costs could turn out to be a lot more than you bargain for...